# Create a network trace for arcgis viewer for silverlight

Tags: silverlight, trace, arcgis

I want to make a network trace with ArcGIS Viewer for silverlight, I'm using ArcGIS 10 Server and Desktop, Can I make it?

I read a blog that wrote about it
https://ambergis.wordpress.com/2011/05/09/network-trace-add-in-for-arcgis-silverlight-viewer/

but I don't get how to make it. Can somebody explain me how to do this?